# Is there a pytorch function to find unique tuples in a given tensor (of size N*h*w*2)?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to extract the unique tuples in a (N * h * w * 2) tensor.

For example, an 1 * 2 * 3 * 2 tensor where there are 6 tuples: `a = torch.tensor([[[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]],  [[4,5], [1,2], [3,4]]]])`

and I am trying to find the indices of the unique tuples (i.e., indices of `[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5]`, where duplicates are removed).

I've already checked out `torch.unique()`, but it seems not working.

Comment: what do you mean "`torch.unique()` not working? what have you tried?

Comment: I think ```a``` may need some conversion before using ```torch.unique()```, but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: I think this can remove duplicates from ```a```:
```a = a.view(-1, 2);
out, inv_idx, counts = torch.unique(a, dim=0, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)```
but the return ```inv_idx``` seems to be indices for where elements in the original input map to in the output, not as expected (indices for where the output unique pairs in the input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compute the difference between all pairs:

```py
d = torch.abs(a.view(-1, 1, 2) - a.view(1, -1, 2)).sum(dim=-1)
```

Then you can find pairs with zero difference (masking non-unique pairs using `triu`):

```
i, j = torch.where((d + torch.triu(torch.ones_like(d))) == 0)
```

Resulting with:

```
i,j
(tensor([4, 5]), tensor([0, 2]))
```

That is the 4th pair in `a` is identical to the 0th, and the 5th is identical to the second.

Comment: But it seems memory consuming because you have to square the (w*h) which might be a large number for a image.

Comment: The size of my image is 640 * 192, so your tensor ```d``` is of size (N * (640*192) * (640*192))
we can not allocate such Tensor at all.....